# Mockups: Coding vs Drawing?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, design-process

This isn't about web design but about interface design in general. Is better to code Interface Mockups or "draw" them in a graphics program, like GIMP, Photoshop, etc.?

Comment: I always get told "sketch your interface,if you do it in photoshop or whatever people will think you're further than you really are. Leave your mockups looking sketchy, just get the basics down so your client knows what to expect and then expand on your UI later."

Comment: It's entirely dependent on the project. There's no universal 'best' answer.

Answer (score 14):

Ask yourself these questions:

- How many UI layouts/options can you explore in 30 minutes by coding? How many can you explore by sketching?
- How often do you get a UI design exactly right on the very first try? If not very often, how quick/easy is it to change a sketch versus a coded mockup?
- Can you instantly identify a color just by looking at its hex/rgb code (not just a ballpark guess, but the exact shade/color)? When you picture a color in your mind, can you immediately translate that to hex? How fast can you pick out a color scheme by typing in hex codes versus using a real color picker?

The fact that you're asking this question tells me that you're most-likely a programmer, not a designer, by training. If you were a designer, then it would be as absurd as developing an application without planning out the class structure, database design, application architecture, etc. and just jumping right into coding—and if you're an experienced developer, then you know what kind of problems this sort of bottom-up development causes.

Similarly, if you jump straight to code without actually *designing* your UI first, then the results aren't going to be pretty, if only because it's impractical to perfect a good design by coding blindly.

Comment: The OP could be talinkg about using a WYSIWYG code editor, with it you can pick colours or even "draw" the objects...

Comment: Actually, coding without designing UI first is quite valid technique. That is, of course, if "coding" doesn't mean UI or UX parts :). Most APIs and libraries are designed in fact without taking UI into account – that would be just impractical.

Comment: @lese, you're pitching a waterfall method. Which can be OK, but the trend these days is to go agile, in which it's very likely that you're working in code from day one.

Comment: @DA01: You're working on code from day one, but you're still applying a top-down methodology. There's nothing in agile that says you can't plan out your data architecture or define UI-first before coding (which I think most agile firms prefer over UML, class diagrams, etc.).

Comment: @thebodzio: Yes, of course, that's what separation of concerns is for. But I'm not referring to coding the backend. When I say coding in terms of the designing part of the question (not the programming analogy I used to illustrate the point--I know, a bit confusing), I mean coding the mockup (CSS + HTML or whatever your UI language may be).

Comment: I think it's a quibble at what we mean by 'code'. I argue that designing *is* coding. It's also sketching, but one can sketch in code (at least at the presentation layer, they can).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: a valuable exaplanation, thank you!

Comment: @lese valid points!

Comment: @DA01: I woudn't go as far as considering "designing" and "coding" to be synonyms.

Comment: @thebodzio they are vague and somewhat generic terms, so open to all sorts of debate.

Comment: Everyone!!! I'm talking about a mockup not the final interface.

Comment: @christopher so are we.

Answer (score 5):

I'd vote for "drawing" first. In GUI, proper layout/presentation is the key and it calls for visual means to be designed. Designing GUI visually lets you rapidly change your design without having to "imagine" each change, "translate it to code" and finally test it. The other way is also possible, but it's rarely better (e.g. project is extremely small, like just a couple of buttons and you're familiar and used to working at "code" level; during design some patterns may emerge, that can be just reused with slight modification).

If you're designing for a specific widget toolkit, you can also use some "GUI designer" application if available. It'll speed up even more GUI design process, because it both shows exactly how designed GUI will look like in running program and can export ready to use GUI description at presentational level.

Comment: "and you're familiar and used to working at "code" level" -> It's important that the UI/UX team *can* work at code level. Every designer doesn't have to be a coder, but the team needs to be able to build everything they design and understand the engineering as much as the visual design.

Comment: I can agree as long as you mean a team as a whole. I think that, when you're just designing UI/UX, not coding it, knowledge of code inner workings can actually hold you back, because you'll tend to avoid some potential solutions only because you'll consider them "too hard to implement". It means that your designs can be stripped of some brilliant ideas, because "toolkit thinking" will lock up parts of your imagination. Then again… it's only one side of the blade :) Besides, the question was about "mock-ups" only.

Comment: I hear the 'hold you back' argument a lot, but find it only comes from visual designers who are stubbornly against learning presentation layer code. These folks also tend to drift towards doing everything in Flash. :) I like to suggest that it's no different than print design. Knowing how printing works doesn't 'hold you back' as a print designer. Rather, it prevents you from creating files that will choke the RIP, or cause the printer to scream at you for 300% ink coverage. It's just about understanding the medium and its associated constraints.

Comment: Designers think "visually", so I don't blame them for not being "hot" for "translating" their ideas to an abstract code. If that wasn't true there woudn't be any WYSIWYG tools out there. I also don't blame designers for being attracted by flash. Look what they can do with it :). I personally prefer way of HTML5, but that's the other thing. A few words about printing then. You've said that knowing it specificity is just "about understanding the medium and its associated constraints". What does constraints do, if not hold you back?

Comment: WYSIWYG isn't for facilitating 'visual thinking'. It's for letting people that don't want to learn something limp along. ;) As for constraints, they define the medium. An architect that can draw great pictures, but doesn't understand the basics of loads and spans is held back to a great extent...as nothing they draw can actually be built.

Comment: Constraints are a wall. Some walls can be brought down – that's where the progress lies, other can't for now. It's good to know they're here, but there will be no progress if all walls will be considered permanent.

Comment: And to further the analogy, you could argue that FLW didn't care about constraints at all, and drew what looked the best and he let engineers figure out how to build it. I admit, FLW left a legacy of great looking structures, however, most engineers will tell you that they are all incredibly fragile, require constant upkeep, and are always a few months away from total collapse. In the end, the visual design might have been spectacular, but the total design of the entire package left a lot to be desired.

Comment: (the site it going to start yelling at us to move to chat but...) I agree that progress lies just on the other side of the constraint. But I don't think you can actually get to that side unless you understand the current constraints fully. All that said, a more pragmatic point: in terms of interaction design, specifically, you simply can't design the interaction without the code. You can propose ideas, but they need to be implemented. That's part of the design process.

Comment: (and a lot of my opinion has been formed working either with or on UX teams that have no idea how to build anything they come up with. They aren't innovating most of the time...but rather designing only half-thought out solutions that aren't practical in terms of implementation, timelines, users, or budgets [which are all additional constraints that, rather than being 'walls' are what helps define the design solution]) P.S.: good discussion!

Comment: WYSIWYG also makes learning easier and makes much less strain for the memory. "It's for letting people that don't want to learn something limp along. ;)" – I get the ";)" :), but even people "willing to learn" created assemblers and higher level languages ;). And about architect whos designs "can't be built"… or can they, if only some effort will be put into breaking barriers? :)

Comment: @DA01: I enjoyed our discussion too! :) Good and high quality arguments from your side, supported by experience. I'm taking your opinion into account. Even though I can't agree with it as a whole, I fully respect it.

Answer (score 3):

For UI design I have three stages with different objectives:

1. **Sketching.** First, you want to get the basic idea down of what elements there will be and how they will fit together. Any fine detail or aesthetic perfectionism at this stage is a distraction. I use a whiteboard and fat erasable pen so it's impossible to get distracted by too much detail and easy to scribble loads of different ideas and start again at any time. I've heard of people who only sketch on small post-it notes or only use their off-hand (e.g. left hand if you're right handed) to force themselves to not pay any attention at all to the aesthetics and focus 100% on the idea and function. (image not mine, [from Frank Prendegast](http://frankprendergast.ie/blog/959/the-best-wireframing-tool-ever-the-whiteboard/))

[image: Photo of whiteboard wireframe]

2. (2!) **Simulating.** Second, you want to get the look down and get feedback, finding out as much as you can about what people's intuitions and unprompted responses are before you start the time consuming implementation work. This should be in whatever you work most effeciently in since if you're doing it right, you should be going 'back to the drawing board' often, seeking out criticism and aiming to identify as many unexpected issues as early as possible. If you're a crazy coding machine and it's what you work most comfortably in, then coding is fine, but most people will work faster in something like Fireworks, Photoshop, dedicated wireframing software, or maybe a UI-driven interface builder like Flash Catalyst (fine if the end product isn't Flash, the goal is to get good feedback before you begin implementation).
3. (3!) **Implementing.** Finally, you implement the thing and aim to do so in a way that allows you to get more feedback early and often.

These three parts of the project cycle have different aims so if it's a big project it makes sense to use the most suitable tool for the job in each stage.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit vague and, as such, as are the answers.

On top of that, projects will vary wildly, as will teams.

That said, there is no 'best'. It's about using all tools in a workflow that makes the most sense for you and your team.

Generically speaking, I'd say this is the type of workflow you should aim for:

1. Sketch. Pencil + paper. Whiteboards. Iterate. Work with as many team members as you can.
2. low-fi mock-ups. Could be PSD, could be visio. Could be paper. User test these.
3. Get to building prototypes. This is where you want to start doing as much as you can in working code. Jump into Photoshop as you need and get the stuff out of it into code as fast as you can. Continue user testing/iterating.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to create mockups using a program that emphasizes **not** creating pixel-perfect layouts. For me that is Balsamiq Mockups, which you can check out at http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups